# How to set up catch-all for non-exist users on multiple domains using postfix+dovecot+mysql

Tags: postfix

I’ve set up my email server using postfix, dovecot and mysql and everything is OK. I currently have several domains hosted on this server. Now I want to set up catch-all for NON-EXIST users only, like this:

a@a.com —> a@a.com
b@a.com(non-exist) —> a@a.com
a@1.com —> a@1.com
b@1.com(non-exist) —> a@1.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need an alias for all, this can be accomplished with an @ alias

From my aliases table in postfix admin

```
address: @domain.com
goto: admin@domain.com
domain: domain.com
active: 1
```

Any email that isn't already defined will fall under this alias.

As an added bonus,  you may want to create an alias and reject it's email.  This can be accomplished with a union query in mysql recipient maps.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_recipient_access.cf

query = select case active when 0 then 'REJECT' when 1 then 'OK' end as access from alias where address  = '%s' union select case active when 0 then 'REJECT' when 1 then 'OK' end as access from mailbox where username = '%s'
```

That will allow you to create alias users that just reject emails as well.